# Setting frequency parameter in SARIMA

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a doubt related to time series forecasting work which I am doing for my project.

I am using SARIMA (Seasonal ARIMA) for forecasting the model since the time series is having seasonality impacts. In SARIMA we have parameters - p,d,q,P,D,Q and m which needs to be passed on. While most of these parameters can be auto selected using auto arima, the term "m", defined as number of seasonal cycles observed in a year (weekly seasonality - 52, monthly seasonality - 12 etc.) is a term which we have to manually provide.

How exactly can we decide this term? As per my time series, the series seems to have slightly improper cycles i.e. sometimes it repeats in a bi-weekly manner and sometimes it repeats in two months. Our dataset is collected in a weekly manner (363 data points for 2 years and 3 months worth of data).

Since there was this confusion for selecting "m", we kept it as 52 (since data points are available on weekly basis) and obtained a decent MAPE (around 9). However, when I increased it to 80, MAPE reduced further to 3 and the forecasted plot was following the actual plot in a much better fashion. When I increased it beyond 80, the code threw some value error.

Does anybody know why this happens?

### Editing this

I increased the test data set and then increased the value of m, which worked.But a higher value of m is not necessarily giving a lower MAPE. value 80 for m gives a low MAPE while values 81 and 85 gives higher values. This seems pretty random but I am sure that this value of m has huge importance in giving out the forecast pattern. I am attaching images here for a better understanding.

[SARIMA with m value 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Fxr.png)

[SARIMA with m value 81](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOySb.png)

[SARIMA with m value 85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1bk2.png)

### Error for high m value

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-8517b4596f58> in <module>
----> 1 model_fit = train_auto_arima(train_df1.DAT_RATE)
      2 model_fit.fit(train_df1.values)
      3 print(f'Params - > \n aic-{model_fit.aic()}, \n get_params-{model_fit.get_params()}')
      4 # forecasting
      5 test_predictions = forecast_over_test_set(model_fit, test_df1.DAT_RATE, train_df1.DAT_RATE)

<ipython-input-89-218545403b7c> in train_auto_arima(df)
     81                stepwise=False,  # We are going with Parallel execution rather than step-wise approach
     82                information_criterion='bic',
---> 83                trace=True, error_action='ignore')
     84 
     85     return arima

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\auto.py in auto_arima(y, exogenous, start_p, d, start_q, max_p, max_d, max_q, start_P, D, start_Q, max_P, max_D, max_Q, max_order, m, seasonal, stationary, information_criterion, alpha, test, seasonal_test, stepwise, n_jobs, start_params, trend, method, transparams, solver, maxiter, disp, callback, offset_test_args, seasonal_test_args, suppress_warnings, error_action, trace, random, random_state, n_fits, return_valid_fits, out_of_sample_size, scoring, scoring_args, with_intercept, sarimax_kwargs, **fit_args)
    320             if seasonal_test_args is not None else dict()
    321         D = nsdiffs(xx, m=m, test=seasonal_test, max_D=max_D,
--> 322                     **seasonal_test_args)
    323 
    324         if D > 0 and exogenous is not None:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\utils.py in nsdiffs(x, m, max_D, test, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     D = 0
--> 107     dodiff = testfunc(x)
    108     while dodiff == 1 and D < max_D:
    109         D += 1

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py in estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(self, x)
    456 
    457         # Get the critical value for m
--> 458         stat = self._compute_test_statistic(x)
    459         crit_val = self._calc_ocsb_crit_val(self.m)
    460         return int(stat > crit_val)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py in _compute_test_statistic(self, x)
    417         # Compute the actual linear model used for determining the test stat
    418         try:
--> 419             regression = self._fit_ocsb(x, m, maxlag, maxlag)
    420         except np.linalg.LinAlgError:  # Singular matrix
    421             if crit_regression is not None:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py in _fit_ocsb(x, m, lag, max_lag)
    341         y_first_order_diff = diff(x, m)
    342         y = diff(y_first_order_diff)
--> 343         ylag = OCSBTest._gen_lags(y, lag)
    344 
    345         if max_lag > 0:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py in _gen_lags(y, max_lag, omit_na)
    334 
    335         # delegate down
--> 336         return OCSBTest._do_lag(y, max_lag, omit_na)
    337 
    338     @staticmethod

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py in _do_lag(y, lag, omit_na)
    319         # Create a 2d array of dims (n + (lag - 1), lag). This looks cryptic..
    320         # If there are tons of lags, this may not be super efficient...
--> 321         out = np.ones((n + (lag - 1), lag)) * np.nan
    322         for i in range(lag):
    323             out[i:i + n, i] = y

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in ones(shape, dtype, order)
    221 
    222     """
--> 223     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    224     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
    225     return a

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: It would be much easier for people to answer "Why does my code throw this value error" if you posted [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the detailed error.

Comment: @DavidBuck ,I cannot share the complete code since it is sensitive(related to project). I can give the below details.

No of datapoints over which SARIMA is running - 121
No of train datapoints - 117
No of test datapoints - 4
Value of m initially set - 52, which gave a MAPE of around 9
Modified value of m - 80, which gave a MAPE of around 3. 
By the way, I did few tweaks like increasing the training dataset and then increasing m value. I found that an increase in m is not necessarily providing a low MAPE. m value 81 and 85 gives higher MAPE than m value 80. I will attach images.